# Resizing and cropping an image that is smaller than the desired/specified dimensions

Tags: ce-image

I am pulling in images / video thumbs using Channel Video (so have no control over source size). If the video doesn't have an HD thumb, the image is much smaller.

I want the image to be resized (stretched) up the way and cropped in these instances. So, no matter what the image size is, it ends up with the dimensions below...

{exp:ce_img:single src='{video:img_url_hd}' width='480' height='308' crop='yes|center,center' output='{made}' quality='68'}

This works correctly for images larger than the above dimensions. But smaller images stay the same.

I guess I am asking:

1) Would I be right in saying the resize and crop has no effect on images smaller than the desired/specified dimensions?

2) Is there a way for force the resizing and cropping on these smaller images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used CE Image, but looking at the documentation it seems you need a parameter "allow_scale_larger" http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#allow_scale_larger

And here's how you can achieve the cropping effect with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/s552453s/ Unfortunately you are limited to cropping from the top instead of center without using Javascript to calculate image heights dynamically and use the padding/margin hack to center it within the div.

Comment: [allow_scale_larger](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#allow_scale_larger)="yes" does the trick. CE Image also crops from the center by default, but that can be changed using the [crop](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#crop)= parameter.

Comment: Perfect! Missed that one. Cheers Kerry